# Speed up processing of grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, multiprocessing, r-future

## Update:

I tried @Adam's approach, which did the trick. Using 8 cores, processing only took 20 minutes. This is great so far.

But I ran into another problem: `foreach`'s `%dopar%` operator forks the workspace `n` times (equal to the number of cores registered). This isn't problematic per se, but with a 20 GB data set this will turn ugly quick.

So a limitation to the original question: *Can this be done without having the whole data set in memory forked `n` times?*

## Situation:

I need to process a large tibble (**>30 million rows**). The tibble is being grouped and a function is called for each group.

In a first step, I reduce the data set by extracting only those rows that share a value in the column `name` like so:

```r
duplicates <- data[duplicated(data$name, fromLast=FALSE) | 
                      duplicated(data$name, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

Right after that, I process these duplicates as stated above:

```r
myTibble <- duplicated %>% group_by(name) 
                       %>% myFunction(., myOtherArgument=myOtherArgument)
                       %>% ungroup
```

The grouping of the duplicates with `group_by` generally results in about **>500k groups**. Each group is being processed by `myFunction()`. This processing, right now, takes about **90 minutes** which is okay, but far from satisfying.

## Question:

*Is there a way to speed up the processing of these groups so that this task won't take 90 minutes but significantly less time?*

(including but not restricted to multiprocessing)

Comment: You can probabily speed it up if you use the `data.table` package. You could also try `dtplyr`, which is suppoused to use the same syntax as `dplyr` but use `data.table` but translates everything to `data.table`

Comment: Can also maybe try using `group_split()` to split the `tibble` into a list split on the groups. Then pass the list into a parallel framework such as `foreach` with `%dopar%`.

Comment: @Adam This helped, but I ran into another problem. I've updated the question accordingly. Thank you regardless!

Comment: Maybe try breaking it up into batches? So a loop within a loop? That way only a subset gets passed into each parallel iteration?

Comment: Can you confirm that most of the time is taken my running `myFunction()`? Do you use a `summarize()`?